# Is there any way to club multiple response for all APIs under one component in Swagger API documentation

Tags: rest, api, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have implemented Swagger documentation for APIs. There multiple response codes for all APIs like - 000,103,130,178, 158 and so one about 50 response codes.

I have implemented them for all APIs. But, there is repetition for all these 50 response code in all APIs.

I want to know if there is any good way to do this.

Below is the sample Documentation -

```
/endpoint:
    post:
      tags:
      - "tag1"
      summary: "My Request"
      description: "My Request description"
      operationId: "Op1"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "My request"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/MyRequest"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MyResponse"
        000:
          description: "Approval"
        103:
          description: "Invalid status value"
        130:
          description: "Invalid Format"
        178:
          description: "Original request not found"
        158:
          description: "Invalid processing code"
        161:
          description: "Withdrawal limit exceeded"
        191:
          description: "Destination not available"
        194:
          description: "Duplicate transaction"
        196:
          description: "System error"
        201:
          description: "Contact Card Issuer"
        205: 
          description: "Contact Card Issuer2"
/endpoint2:
    post:
      tags:
      - "tag2"
      summary: "My Request2"
      description: "My Request description2"
      operationId: "Op2"
      consumes:
      - "application/json"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      parameters:
      - in: "body"
        name: "body"
        description: "Myrequest"
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/MyRequest2"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "successful operation"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/MyResponse2"
        000:
          description: "Approval"
        103:
          description: "Invalid status value"
        130:
          description: "Invalid Format"
        178:
          description: "Original request not found"
        158:
          description: "Invalid processing code"
        161:
          description: "Withdrawal limit exceeded"
        191:
          description: "Destination not available"
        194:
          description: "Duplicate transaction"
        196:
          description: "System error"
        201:
          description: "Contact Card Issuer"
        205: 
          description: "Contact Card Issuer2"
```

Comment: Are 000, 130, 205 etc. used as [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)? Or are these codes returned in some field in the response body, e.g. `{"error": "103", ...}`?

Comment: These are error codes which will be returned if there is an error in sending response apart from the normal 200 response.

Comment: Can you add an example of an actual error response with one of these error codes, i.e a ["raw" HTTP response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_message_body) with the status line, headers and response body? Putting these codes under `responses` alongside 200 does not seem right, and seeing a raw response would help understand how to fix the Swagger definition.